# Disabling error checks for bower_components folder in Netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans, bower

Is there a way to disable error checks for every file inside bower_components directory?

I've figured it out that Netbeans registers resources to be bypassed during validation checking in this file:

**C:\Users\userdir\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\var\attributes.xml**.

Here is an example of how it registers a resource that is not supposed to be checked:

```
<fileobject name="C:|Users|userdir|Documents|NetBeansProjects|HTML5Application|public_html|index.html">
    <attr name="disable_error_checking" boolvalue="true"/>
</fileobject>
```

The problem is that I can't change this file manually, it appears that this file is manipulated according to some configuration placed somewhere else (I've also searched inside the project's config files).

Any ideas?